# How to unprotect memory region spanning several pages on one go?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm

I'm trying to unprotect a chunk of memory region which spans several pages.
I'm using this code to unprotect one page of the memory however i need to unprotect several pages at one go as i'm experiencing segfault when accessing other pages I have a start address and an end address on hand however the function below makes use of my start address `rdi` and gives me write access to the current page, how can i make use of the end address `r15` such that i can have write access spanning `rdi -> r15` memory pages:

For example: write access on pages spanning from `rdi` = 0x4012a0 to `r15` = 0x402340 address in one go

```
call getpagesize
; rax has 0x1000
mov rcx, rax
; save rax for later use when passing to mprotect
sub rcx, 0x1
not rcx
mov rdi, %1
and rdi, rcx
; AND them and the result will be stored in rcx
; rdi must hold the page_start address
mov rsi, rax
; rsi must have the page length
mov rdx, 0x7
; read+write+exec = 0x7
call mprotect
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't quite right:

```
; rsi must have the page length
```

Here, `rsi` is the second argument to the `mprotect()` call, which is supposed to be the length of the area you're changing. If you want the length of the area to be larger than one page then you need `rsi` to be greater than the value you got from `call getpagesize`.

Specifically; maybe you want something more like:

```
    call getpagesize
    ; rax has 0x1000
    mov rcx, rax
    ; save rax for later use when passing to mprotect
    sub rcx, 0x1
    not rcx
    mov rdi, %1
    and rdi, rcx
    ; AND them and the result will be stored in rcx
    ; rdi must hold the page_start address

    mov rsi, r15      ;rsi = end
    sub rsi,rdi       ;rsi = end - aligned_start = length

    mov rdx, 0x7
    ; read+write+exec = 0x7
    call mprotect
```